# for vs forEach vs map

Tags: javascript, bucles

Trabajando en JavaScript, tengo dos arrays que necesito combinar para genera una concatenación de todos sus elementos, por ejemplo:

```
var array1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];

resultado = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3"];
```

Para hacer eso se me ocurren 3 métodos diferentes: usando el clásico bucle [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code#The_standard_for_loop), usando el método [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), o usando el método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), de las siguientes formas:

**for**

```js
var array1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];

var resultado = [];
for(var x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < array2.length; y++) {
    resultado.push(array1[x] + array2[y]);
  };
};

console.log(resultado);
```

**forEach**

```js
var array1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];

var resultado = [];
array1.forEach(function(valor1) {
  array2.forEach(function(valor2) {
    resultado.push(valor1 + valor2);
  });
});

console.log(resultado);
```

**map**

```js
var array1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];

var resultado = [];
array1.map(function(valor1) {
  array2.map(function(valor2) {
    resultado.push(valor1 + valor2);
  });
});

console.log(resultado);
```

Los tres métodos atraviesan ambos arrays y con los tres obtengo el mismo resultado (como se puede ver en los ejemplos arriba). Ahora mis preguntas:

- ¿Cuáles son las ventajas/inconvenientes de cada método?
- ¿Hay alguno que se debería usar sobre los otros?¿O dependiendo de la situación?
- ¿Existe algún método que haga algo similar y sea mejor (p.e.: más eficiente o rápido)

Comment: en esta pregunta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034392/what-use-does-the-javascript-foreach-method-have-that-map-cant-do se habla soble la diferencia entre foreach y map

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ¿Cuáles son las ventajas/inconvenientes de cada método?

Es una pregunta bastante genérica. El clásico `for` y el más moderno `forEach`, son básicamente lo mismo. De hecho, `forEach` nace como una alternativa más moderna al clásico `for` (como en la mayoría de lenguajes). El uso de `for` es más razonable para hacer un número **dado** de interaciones, mientras que `forEach` es para recorrer colleciones. La ventaja de `for` es que es bastante rápido en comparación de `forEach` (aunque este no es lento).

> ¿Hay alguno que se debería usar sobre los otros? ¿O dependiendo de la situación?

La respuesta es siempre depende. Como dije en el punto anterior, `for` y `forEach` si bien se pueden usar para las mismas cosas, el último está pensado principalmente para recorrer coleciones (de ahí su nombre).

`Map`, por otro lado, está pensado para iterar una colección pero con el objetivo de **operar esa colección** para **devolver una nueva** a partir de ésta. Este algoritmo funciona igual en lenguajes como Java.

> ¿Existe algún método que haga algo similar y sea mejor (p.e.: más
>   eficiente o rápido)

Para responder esta pregunta podemos hacer un pequeño benchmark comparando las diferentes estructuras:

- for
- forEach
- map
- for in
- for of

#### Prueba de rendimiento

Esta sencilla prueba de rendimiento arroja resultados interesantes. Al parecer `map` es más rápido que `forEach` en **Gecko** que en **Webkit** por una diferencia considerable.

```js
var array = [];
var runs = 100;

(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) array[i] = i;

  function runTest(name, f) {
      var totalTime = 0;
      console.time(name);

      for (var r = 0; r < runs; r++) {
          f();
      }
      return console.timeEnd(name);
  }

  function doNothing(v) { }

  runTest('for', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          doNothing(array[i]);
      }
  });
  
  runTest('forEach', function() {
    array.forEach(doNothing);
 });
  
  runTest('for in', function() {
   for(var i in array) {
     doNothing(array[i]);
    }
  });
  
  runTest('for of', function() {
   for(var i of array) {
     doNothing(i)
    }
  });
  
  runTest('map', function() {
   array.map(doNothing);
  })
})();
```

#### Conclusiones

Las últimas versiones de **Firefox**, **Chrome** y **Edge**, arrojan lo siguiente:

- `Map` es más rápido en `Gecko` que en todos los motores.
- `for` es la estructura más rápida de todas.
- `for in` es la estructura más lenta de todas.
- `forEach` es más rápida que `map` en `Webkit` y `Chakra`.
- `Chakra` es el que más tiempo toma entre los motores.
- `for of` toma casi el mismo tiempo que `forEach`.

Obviamente estos resultados pueden variar entre versiones de motores/navegadores, pero creo los resultados sean radicales entre ellas.

Comment: Genial respuesta. Una pregunta: ¿qué hay del soporte? Me he encontrado con que `forEach` no funciona bien en aplicaciones web desarrolladas con Cordova/Phonegap (en algunos dispositivos), ¿es algo que con `map` debería preocuparme?

Comment: A partir de iOS 8 creo que Cordova hace uso de WKWebview que soporta `forEach` y `map` perfectamente (para Android 4+ no creo tengas problemas), pero si se desea bastante backward compatibility entonces mejor usar algo más clásico.

Comment: Creo que estamos ignorando un detalle importante: map devuelve un array, es una función para transformar los datos en otros. Por tanto es más lento y requiere más memoria. Si no vas a usar el array que devuelve, usa siempre cualquier otro método