# Calcular la longitud de cada string dentro de un array con el metodo .map

Tags: javascript, array, string

Buenas,
No tengo claro como funciona el metodo `map`, realiza una función por cada elemento del `array` como `foreach`? Gracias

**Querría saber cómo hacer esto =>**

Take an array of strings and turn it into an array of numbers indicating the length of each string using `Array.map`.

```
- `['Los Angeles', 'New York', 'Huston'] => [11, 8, 6]`
```

Answer (score 3):

En una simple linea:

```js
var a = ['Los Angeles', 'New York', 'Huston'].map(x => x.length);

console.log(a);
```

> El método map() crea un nuevo array con los resultados de la llamada a la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos.

[+ info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

Comment: Gracias, es como foreach entonces?

Comment: @fran - [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26528/6491)  y [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034392/what-use-does-the-javascript-foreach-method-have-that-map-cant-do) tienes una explicación buena

Comment: Otra preguntilla; Como haria para sumar esto, gracias
Sum the contents on an array of numbers using `Array.reduce`
 var myString = [1,2,3];

Comment: @fran - Si [lees](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) la documentación ahí esta todo explicado y con el ejemplo exacto que buscas

Answer (score 0):

Si amigo es muy parecido al `forEach` por cada una de las iteraciones hacemos cambios en el elemento y generamos un nuevo `array` con los cambios espero te ayude saludos

```js
var a = ['Los Angeles', 'New York', 'Huston'].map(x => x.length);

$("#btn").click(function(){
  $(".p").text(a)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn" type="button" name="button">cambiar array con map</button>
<p class="p">'Los Angeles', 'New York', 'Huston'</p>
```