# Conseguir índice de un objeto en un Array de objetos proporcionando un atributo del objeto

Tags: javascript, array

¿Cómo puedo eliminar un elemento de un `Array` de objetos?

```
var arreglo = [
    {
        "cantidad" : "2",
        "valor"    : 468,
        "producto" : "Banana",
        "idprod"   : 1
    },
    {
        "cantidad" : "3",
        "valor"    : 678,
        "producto" : "cebolla",
        "idprod"   : 2
    }
];
```

No conozco el índice del objeto que quiero eliminar, solo conozco la propiedad `idprod` de dicho objeto. ¿Cómo hago para averiguar el índice del objeto guiándome por esta propiedad?

```
var indice = arreglo.indexOf(??); // obtener el indice
arreglo.splice(indice, 1); // 1 es la cantidad de elemento a eliminar
```

Creo que este sería el procedimiento pero no sé cómo obtener la posición.

Comment: De duplicado, al menos de la pregunta que indicais, no tiene nada. Esta pregunta es **sobre como localizar el objeto interno**. Me suena de que hay otras por ahí, pero la propuesta desde luego que no O_O

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esto lo puedes lograr con el método [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) de **JavaScript**, no necesitas obligatoriamente saber la posición exacta del objeto a eliminar, solo necesitas comparar el `idprod` de cada objeto y cuando sea igual al `id` que deseas eliminar entonces sobreescribimos el `array`con los objetos restantes ignorando el actual:

```js
var arreglo = [{"cantidad":"2","valor":468,"producto":"Banana","idprod":1},{"cantidad":"3","valor":678,"producto":"cebolla","idprod":2}];

var eliminar = 2;

arreglo = arreglo.filter(function(dato){
    if(dato.idprod == eliminar){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(arreglo);
```

En el ejemplo estoy eliminando el `idprod: 2`

Comment: en realidad no lo estas eliminando, lo estas sobreescribiendo

Comment: @JackNavaRow tienes razón, edición hecha :D

Answer (score 4):

Por medio de un ciclo `For in` lo puedes realizar, ingresando a la propiedad idprod de cada objeto recorrido en el array. y cuando cumpla con el id que quieres eliminar obtienes el indice para poder eliminarlo.

```js
var arreglo = [{
                "cantidad":"2",
                "valor":468,
                "producto":"Banana",
                "idprod":1
                },          
                {
                "cantidad":"3",
                "valor":678,
                "producto":"cebolla",
                "idprod":2
                }
              ];
              
  var eliminar = 1;

  for (var indice in arreglo){
  
    var id = arreglo[indice].idprod;

    if(id == eliminar){
      
      var index = indice;
    }
  }
  
  arreglo.splice(index, 1);
  console.log(arreglo);
```

Comment: si no agregas el otro parametro del arreglo.splice va a eliminar todo desde la posicion que encontrastes a la ultima, si tienes dudas, cambia el valor eliminar a 1

Comment: @JackNavaRow Muchas Gracias! , no lo sabia.

Answer (score 3):

Usando filter y borrando con splice

```
    var arreglo = [{ "cantidad": "2", "valor": 468, "producto": "Banana", "idprod": 1 }, { "cantidad": "3", "valor": 678, "producto": "cebolla", "idprod": 2 }];


    var IdProducto = 1 //producto a buscar     

    arreglo.splice(getIndice(IdProducto), 1); //elimina el producto del arreglo

    console.log(arreglo);

    function getIndice(IdProducto) {
        var Indice = -1;
        arreglo.filter(function (producto, i) {
            if (producto.idprod === IdProducto) {
                Indice = i;
            }
        });
        return Indice;
    }
```

Comment: esta es la respuesta mas acorde al usuario pero creo que falta una mejor redaccion

Answer (score 2):

Una solución rápida, puedes generar un nuevo array filtrando el id que quieres eliminar.

```js
var arreglo = [{"cantidad":"2","valor":468,"producto":"Banana","idprod":1},{"cantidad":"3","valor":678,"producto":"cebolla","idprod":2}];

idBanana = 1;
arregloSinBanana = arreglo.filter(function(el) {
    return el.idprod!== idBanana ;
});
    
console.log(arregloSinBanana);
```

> El método **filter()** crea una nueva matriz con todos los elementos que
>   pasan la prueba dada por la función proporcionada.
>   [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: que diferencia hay de esto a hacer un for?? porque realmente hace lo mismo

Comment: Para poco valores como lo maneja @sofira no hay tanto problema, es más sencillo de leer el código. Pero con un loop de for si hay una gran diferencia para la velocidad que recorre el array.

Comment: te lo dejo para fines practicos https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26508/for-vs-foreach-vs-map mira quien es mas rapido

Answer (score 2):

Puedes eliminar con la funcion `splice`:

```js
var arreglo = [{
  "cantidad": "2",
  "valor": 468,
  "producto": "Banana",
  "idprod": 1
}, {
  "cantidad": "3",
  "valor": 678,
  "producto": "cebolla",
  "idprod": 2
}];

var eliminar = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
  if (arreglo[i].idprod === eliminar) {

    arreglo.splice(i, 1);
  }

}

console.log(arreglo);
```

Comment: tu ejemplo me incomomda un poco, tienes el `arreglo.length` que al eliminar va a cambiar la dimension del arreglo y no se que pueda pasar cuando cambie la dimencion

Comment: acabo de hacer la prueba y cuando lo elimina redimensiona el arreglo por lo tanto no hay alguna posibilidad de error cuando elimine un elemento del arreglo

Answer (score 2):

Una variacion de [DanielEsteban](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/124542/28035), utilizando **prototype**, es mas controlado y puedes hacer editarlo de acuerdo a tus necesidades, le agrege un poco mas de validaciones y lo optimicé un poco mas.

```js
Array.prototype.borrarPorIdProducto = function(idProducto){
    //buscamos posicion 
        let indice = -1;
        this.filter(function (producto, i) {
            if (producto.idprod === idProducto) {
                indice = i;
               return;
            }
        });
        if(indice >=0){
          this.splice(indice,1);
        }
}    
    
    
    var arreglo =[{
 "cantidad": "2",
 "valor": 468,
 "producto": "Banana",
 "idprod": 1
}, {
 "cantidad": "3",
 "valor": 678,
 "producto": "cebolla",
 "idprod": 2
}]

    var IdProducto = 1 //producto a buscar    
    arreglo.borrarPorIdProducto(1);
    console.log(arreglo);
```

Tambien te coloco la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) del **array.splice**