# Obtener el return de un addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Tengo unos botones en mi Html con un atributo value, en la const selection_item, convierto ese file list a un array en la const  searchingBtns, y recorro el array con un .map, pero quiero que al hacer click sobre cada uno de los botones capturar el value, eso funciona bien , pero necesito sacar ese valor en la variable let t para usarlo en otra parte de mi aplicación, lo hice de esta manera pero no me muestra nada, que podría hacer en este caso como puedo sacar ese valor? con return tampoco funciona colocando todo dentro de una funcion

Gracias por la ayuda

```
const selection_item = document.getElementsByClassName("selection_item");
    const searchingBtns = Array.from(selection_item);
    
    
    let t = "";
    
    
    searchingBtns.map((btn)=>{
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            t = this.getAttribute('value');
        });
    })
    
    
    console.log(t);
```

Comment: Me pregunto por qué no usas `t` dentro del listener ¿? Como pretendes hacerlo, tendrías que asignar a `t` el  resultado de la función... no le veo demasiado sentido a eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes devolver valores en funciones cuando se dispara un evento, pero sí puedes actualizar variables globales y usarlas en otras funciones.

El problema aquí es que defines los eventos donde vas a actualizar la variable y debes esperar a que se ejecuten para poder ver el resultado.

```js
const selection_item = document.getElementsByClassName("selection_item");
const searchingBtns = Array.from(selection_item);
   
let t = "";
    
searchingBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        t = this.value;
        // Aquí ya se actualizó la variable
        console.log(t);
    });
});

// Puedes usar la variable en otras funciones
document.querySelector('#ver-variable').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(t == '') {
        console.log('Todavía no se asigna valor, haz clic en algún botón de arriba');
    } else {
        console.log('El valor de t es: ' + t);
    }
});


// En este momento aún no se han realizado clics en los botones
// Por eso es que t sigue siendo una cadena vacía
console.log(t);
```

```html
<p>
<button class="selection_item" value="1">1</button>
<button class="selection_item" value="2">2</button>
<button class="selection_item" value="3">3</button>
</p>

<button id="ver-variable">Ver variable</button>
```

Una mejora a tu código es remplazar estas dos líneas:

```
const selection_item = document.getElementsByClassName("selection_item");
const searchingBtns = Array.from(selection_item);
```

Por una sola, usando [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) que no devuelve un arreglo, pero sí una lista de nodos que puedes recorrer con [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) que, para este caso, es mejor que `.map()` y en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26528/54039) se explica porqué.

```
const searchingBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.selection_item');
```