# sacar variable de una función - javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un select donde muestro unas tallas y en una función traigo el texto que me muestra el select, pero necesito poder sacar dicho valor en una variable por fuera de la función y no he podido lograrlo.

```js
<select  id="lista1" name="lista1">
        <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
        <option value="TALLA_M">M</option>
        <option value="TALLA_S">S</option>
</select>

var select = document.getElementById('lista1');
select.addEventListener('change',
  function(){
    var selectedOption = this.options[select.selectedIndex];
    console.log(selectedOption.text);
  }
   
  );
  
  //SI REVISO LA CONSOLA ME MUESTRA LA TALLA QUE SELECCIONE PERO NECESITO SACAR EL VALOR DE LA CONSOLA Y PASARLO A UNA VARIBALE POR FUERA DE LA FUNCIÓN
```

Comment: Puedes usar [https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types](variablesglobales) ó mandar llamar la función a la que necesitas pasarle el valor del `select`

Comment: pero como seria en el código que tengo, lo he intentado pero no lo he logrado

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué quieres hacer con el valor? Si es asignarlo a otro elemento, ¿no es mejor hacerlo dentro de la función del listener? Si quieres sacarla fuera, como dice @Robinson, declara la variable en el ámbito globlal y asígnala en la función.

Comment: el valor de "selectedOption.text" esta bien solo quiero sacar el resultado que me muestra en consola a una variable que la pueda utilizar por fuera de la función.

Comment: puedes usar variables globales, tal cual como te indican en el primer comentario-

Comment: me puedes dar un ejemplo es que no he logrado hacerlo en mi código..

Comment: Que la primera línea de tu script sea la variable que quieres implementar `var tuvariable = 0` por ejemplo

Comment: pero como hago para sacar selectedOption.text del console.log en una variable lo intentado pero no he podido

Comment: Ah! quieres el texto, perdón entendí mal, ya modifico la respuesta

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener el return de un addEventListener](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445524/obtener-el-return-de-un-addeventlistener)

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres, no das un contexto de tu problema y básicamente a cada pregunta respondes lo mismo "es que quiero sacar el ...",

Answer (score 1):

Puedes leer el siguiente [articulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types), y como ejemplo quedaría así:

```
<select  id="lista1" name="lista1">
        <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
        <option value="1">M</option>
        <option value="2">S</option>
</select>

<script>
var mivariable =0;

  var select = document.getElementById('lista1');
select.addEventListener('change',
  function(){
    var selectedOption = this.options[select.selectedIndex];
    mivariable = document.getElementById('lista1').value;
  }
   
  );
</script>
```

Te recomiendo que a los `select` le agregues como valor un numero y no un texto, facilita mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes valerte de una variable global que esté declarada antes de la función.

En el ejemplo, declaro la variable global `ultimoTexto` para ese efecto.
Puedes ver el valor que está almacenado en esa variable en la consola en cualquier momento haciendo clic en el botón.

```js
let ultimoTexto;

const select = document.getElementById('lista1');
select.addEventListener('change',
  function(){
    var selectedOption = this.options[select.selectedIndex];
    ultimoTexto = selectedOption.text;
  }
);

function mostrarVariable() {
  console.log(ultimoTexto);
}
```

```html
<select  id="lista1" name="lista1">
  <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
  <option value="TALLA_M">M</option>
  <option value="TALLA_S">S</option>
</select>

<button onclick="mostrarVariable()">Imprimir valor</button>
```

Haz clic el botón *Ejecutar* para probar el código aquí mismo en la respuesta.

Como ves, la misma variable está accesible en cualquier parte del script, después de que ha sido declarada.

Debes tomar en cuenta que se desaconseja el uso de variables globales de manera indiscriminada. En javascript a veces no hay muchas otras opciones. Yo cumplo con responder a tu pregunta, pero no podría decir que aconsejo que resuelvas el problema que tienes a mano de esta forma.

**EDICIÓN**

El AP ha solicitado el código sin el botón para ver el resultado, lo dejo por aquí:

```js
let ultimoTexto;

const select = document.getElementById('lista1');
select.addEventListener('change',
  function(){
    var selectedOption = this.options[select.selectedIndex];
    ultimoTexto = selectedOption.text;
  }
);
```

```html
<select  id="lista1" name="lista1">
  <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
  <option value="TALLA_M">M</option>
  <option value="TALLA_S">S</option>
</select>
```

La funcionalidad se mantiene, la variable global tiene el texto seleccionado después de cada cambio en el `<select>`.

Comment: pero me sirve sin el boton , solo que se ejecute cuando cambio de <option>

Comment: El botón lo puse en el ejemplo para que puedas ver rápidamente que la variable SI tiene el valor. Considero que tu pregunta está respondida y es normal que te toque adaptar el código para TU propósito.

Comment: la puedes colocar sin el boton?

Comment: pero el ejemplo que estas colocando no sirve por que si lo coloco con un <select> no funciona

Comment: No comprendo, el ejemplo está hecho con un `<select>`, ¿no?

Comment: @Giovanny, edité la respuesta y dejé un ejemplo sin el botón. Un saludo.

Comment: me aparece el siguiente error en consola "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectedIndex')"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146060/discussion-between-jachguate-and-giovanny).